# Dot product between two vectors transformed by orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices, transpose

I am reading through the "Matrix Transformations" chapter of [this book](https://www.amazon.de/Foundations-Game-Engine-Development-Mathematics/dp/0985811749/ref=asc_df_0985811749/?tag=googshopde-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=310817730623&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=10270698525271890731&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9061136&hvtargid=pla-337511948532&psc=1&th=1&psc=1&tag=&ref=&adgrpid=70301320788&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvadid=310817730623&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=10270698525271890731&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9061136&hvtargid=pla-337511948532) and more specifically on Orthogonal Matrices. I understand their properties and understand that multiplying vectors by them is an affine transformation, so the dot product between two vectors will be the same as between the same vectors multiplied by the same orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{M}$.

However this proof from the book confuses me to no end:

[image]

And more specifically this:

$$\mathbf{(Ma)\cdot (Mb)=(Ma)^T (Mb)}$$

What exactly is happening on the right side of the equation? Is the transpose of $\mathbf{Ma}$ somehow the reciprocal of the dot operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea here is that a dot-product can be interpreted as the product (as in matrix multiplication) of a row-vector and a column-vector. Note that vectors are considered to be "column-vectors" by default, so treating a vector as a row-vector means that we need to transpose it.

For example, if we have the vectors
$$
\mathbf u = \pmatrix{1\\2\\3}, \quad \mathbf v = \pmatrix{-2\\0\\1},
$$
then we can express the dot-product $\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v$ as the matrix product
$$
\mathbf u \cdot \mathbf v = \mathbf u^T \mathbf v = \pmatrix{1&2&3} \pmatrix{-2\\0\\1} = (1)(-2) + (2)(0) + (3)(1) = 1.
$$
Note that there is a slight (and very common) abuse of notation happening here: we have the product of a $1 \times 3$ and $3\times 1$ matrix, which results in a $1\times 1$ matrix. However, instead of writing our answer as the $1\times 1$ matrix $[1]$, we think of it as simply being the scalar $1$.  In general, $1\times 1$ matrices are thought of as scalars.

From there the rest of the steps in the proof use the properties of the transpose as it relates to matrix-multiplication, then reinterprets the final $\mathbf a^T\mathbf b$ as a dot-product.

Comment: Hey thanks for that, I think I get it now.

Comment: the final   converts ***a*** back to column vector so we can perform dot product between them. Thanks, I get it.

Comment: @GeorgiB.Nikolov Glad to help. If you're happy with my answer, I'd appreciate it if you could "accept" my answer by clicking the check mark ($\checkmark$) on the top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider the vectors $Ma$ and $Mb$ to be $n\times 1$ matrices, then the product $(Ma)^T(Mb)$ is just matrix multiplication, $\sum_{i=1}^n (Ma)_i(Mb)_i=(Ma)\cdot (Mb)$.

We use this form of the dot product, so that we can expand the brackets and use the fact that the matrix product of $M$ and $M^T$ is the identity matrix.